# Quantikz: Move gategroup in foreground

Tags: quantikz

Here is an small example of a quantum circuit (drawn with quantikz) that has 3 `gategroup`s.
How can I move Charlie's gategroup (blue) to the front so that it is also on top of Bob's gategroup, like Alice's?

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}

\begin{document}
\begin{quantikz}
    \lstick{$\ket{\psi}$} & \gate{X} \gategroup[1,steps=2,style={dashed,rounded corners,fill=gray!20,inner ysep=1pt},background,label style={label position=above,anchor=mid}]{{Alice}} & \gate{Y} \gategroup[2,steps=1,style={dashed,rounded corners,fill=blue!20,inner ysep=-2pt},background,label style={label position=right,anchor=mid,xshift=10pt,yshift=-4pt,rotate=-90}]{{Charlie}} \\
    \lstick{$\ket{\phi}$} & \gate{Z} \gategroup[1,steps=2,style={dashed,rounded corners,fill=gray!20,inner ysep=1pt},background,label style={label position=below,anchor=north,yshift=-4pt}]{{Bob}} & \gate{Y}
\end{quantikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you'd copy your codesnippet into a fresh file and compile it ... it won't. So please add the missing lines to your question. Thank you